# Menu selection/focus jumps around

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

I'm using the iPad app 1.1.0.132. When I select my Inbox or Achievements in the menu on the left then the focus (red marking bar) jumps to the respective icon and the popup (inbox or achievements) opens up. However after a moment it jumps back to where I was before. Shouldn't it jump back only in case I close the popup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct – there was definitely room for improvement there. I have changed the menu transitions there so that the selection only reverts whenever the user leaves the achievements/inbox screens.

This change will be visible in **beta version 1.2.0.139**.